# pickadate.js how to disable every Sunday

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple calendar set up to via pickadate.js. How can I disable every sunday on the calendar? I noticed it having a `disable:[]` in place but not sure how to specify a day

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
weekdaysShort: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
showMonthsShort: true
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documents says

```
//Using integers representing days of the week (from 1 to 7):
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    disable: [
        1, 4, 7
    ]
})
```

so if you want to disable sunday then:

```
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
     weekdaysShort: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
     showMonthsShort: true,
     disable: [7]
});
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. I read that in the documentation but thought that was referring to the actual dates. Thanks again!

Comment: @repeater09 you're welcome. I believe if you want to disable dates it's just the same but it should be an array regards!