# pickadate.js - disable dates in the past (including today) and also disable every sunday

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

I've had no problem disabling dates in the past (including today) with the below configuration. However I'm not sure how to add to this to also disable every Sunday

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
 disable: [{from: [0, 0, 0], to: dateToday}],
});
```

Is there something I'm missing to have this also block every Sunday?

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171909/pickadate-js-how-to-disable-every-sunday

Comment: use `min` for start date and `disable` to disable Sunday. disabling all previous dates can work, but I believe `min & max` were meant for this restrictions. or you can simply add that day into array (as disable takes an array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, `disable` takes an array, so you can simply disable Sunday by adding `1` into the array. More about this can be found in the [documentation](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#disable-dates-all)

```js
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
 disable: [
   {from: [0, 0, 0], to: true},
   1
 ],
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/themes/default.css" id="theme_base">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/themes/default.date.css" id="theme_date">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.js"></script>
<script src="http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.date.js"></script>
<input class="datepicker">
```